Getting subsequent GET calls for some PUT, POST APIs in web site
I'm observing subsequent GET calls for some PUT, POST API. I already checked the code and there is no GET calls created for those endpoints. But I'm seeing this call in my server logs.
Say for example I have a endpoint PUT /api/email/subscribe. I'm seeing calls for GET /api/email/subscribe . Which causing "Method Not Allowed" error to be thrown since there is no GET call integrated for those endpoints.
Also observed a bit of uneven pattern. Many seem be from web crawlers such as bingbot, facebookexternalhit , or a android VM which used to run apps called Dalvik and some from windows NT. Example:
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +https://www.comscore.com/Web-Crawler)
Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) Chrome/116.0.1938.76 Safari/537.36

Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 13; Zenfone Max Pro M1 Build/TSV1.220628.057)

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

but there are few normal requests as well like
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1

Not sure if I can block these requests entirely and how to proceed. Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Why would you want to "block" these requests, if they are already getting a 405 Method Not Allowed response?

just to optimize my server resources. If I block them using WAF rules then they wouldn't simply reach the server itself.
